Rhythmically bound?
I'm wondering how bound I am to the (let's say in this case) 4/4 time in blues/jazz. Let's use the first two bars of Summertime in A minor (playing from a lead sheet). The notes are E C E. The last E is a whole note, telling me to hold it for 4 beats.
Now my question is, how rhythmically bound to this am I? What if I wanna make it really slow and bluesy using trombone and plunger. And if I then feel that holding the last E for 4 beats is too little. So I wanna hold it, say 6 beats. And not lower the BPM of the song in general.
Would this be considered playing with bad rhythm? It would definitely throw the backing and comping harmony off.

Have you ever listened to jazz? Extending/delaying something and then skipping/rushing to catch up is like 75% of melody.

Note, changing the bpm doesn’t alter the rhythm at all.

Context is important to this answer.
You tagged jazz and blues so that would suggest you might be reading a lead sheet. If that’s the case, many rhythmic liberties are taken by those who read lead sheets and play melody in general. Lengthening a note or even changing a rhythm is completely acceptable in this situation and in these styles. You have to do these things within the boundaries of common sense and taste. If there is a harmonic change where you are sustaining a note it is up to you to make sure the note you held over is not going to clash with the changing harmony.
Now if you are playing an arrangement with specifically written parts then playing accurate note durations and written rhythms are extremely important in order for the band to sound “tight” and also for the music to sound the way it was conceived by the arranger.
EDIT: I want to make sure I’m understanding your question and that is you want to extend the length of a note into the next bar but not have the accompaniment change. If you expect to hold a note for an extra two bears and also have the accompanists extend that bar for an extra two beats with you that is definitely not done.

I did edit, adding that. Playing from lead sheet. How would the compers know that Im playing a wholetone as 6 beats?

They really don’t have to know if what you’re doing works within the overall scheme. I edited and added to my answer, check it out.

This rubato happens all the time in jazz - it's one of its joys. However, the beat goes on, 4/4 doesn't usually end up as 6/4.
Of course, that 2nd E could be held for longer - 5 beats are available anyway, but if you wanted 6 or more, you have to be aware that the chord in that next bar will support that note, and not make it sound like a mistake.
If working from a sheet, writing in a fermata, or pause mark, might do the job. But if working in an ensemble, you'll have to be aware that everyone's idea of how long a pause is will vary.
There's no concrete answer, just use your ears, and hear what works, and what sounds like a mistake. Your choice!

You could hold that E for 4 bars quite effectively, with the comping continuing as usual.  But there wouldn't then be any place to put the notes for 'and the livin' is easy'.  They'd just have to be omitted.
I suppose you COULD ask everyone else to add a bar or two and then continue as written.  Not sure anyone would like the effect much!
